# Splitting all files in a folder with pdftk

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, pdf, pdftk

I'm trying to use pdftk to split a folder containing pdf files into their constituent pages. Here is my code:

```
~/MCO/MCOs$ for file in *.pdf; do pdftk "$file" burst; done
```

The command itself does not seem to be incorrect, but I get a java error as follows:

```
Unhandled Java Exception in create_output():
Unhandled Java Exception in main():
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at gnu.gcj.runtime.NameFinder.lookup(libgcj.so.16)
  at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(libgcj.so.16)
  at java.lang.Throwable.stackTraceString(libgcj.so.16)
  at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.16)
  at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.16)
```

There seems to be some recognition of this [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/972340), but it is unclear how/if it has been resolved.

I'm trying to get my output such that for an example file 'ad.pdf' is split into 'ad.pdf_01' and 'ad.pdf_02' if it contains two pages.

Comment: Is the issue specific to when pdftk is run in a loop, or do you get the same error when run singly?

Comment: Specifically when it is run in a loop.

Comment: According to the issue you linked it has been resolved in pdftk 2.01, what version are you using?

Comment: @steeldrivers answer worked for me. It was probably an issue of overwriting to the same file while it was still open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that `pdftk burst` defaults to naming its output files as `pg_0001.pdf`, `pg_0002.pdf` and so on regardless of the input file name.

Exactly *why* that causes errors is not clear - possibly it starts to process the next file before the previous output file(s) have been closed. In any case, overwriting files is obviously not desirable in this case - so the solution is to change the output on a per-file basis.

According to the `pdftk` manual page:

```
                    To name these pages yourself, supply a
printf-styled format string via the output section.  For
example, if you want pages named: page_01.pdf, page_02.pdf,
etc., pass output page_%02d.pdf to pdftk.
```

so for example you could do

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftk "$file" burst output "${file%.pdf}-%02d.pdf"; done
```

which for inputs `fileA.pdf`, `fileB.pdf` will result in output files `fileA-01.pdf`, `fileA-02.pdf`, ... `fileB-nm.pdf` (removing and re-adding the `.pdf` extension after the numeric suffix).

If you *really* want `ad.pdf` --> `ad.pdf_01` that would be `"${file}_%02d"`.

Answer (score 1):

I would

- Make sure your pdftk is at version 2.01 because the issue should be
  fixed, according to the issue you linked.
- Try with a different JRE
  installed, link OpenJDK or Oracle JRE.
- Try [Sejda](http://www.sejda.org/), command line,
  open source and does split PDF files (among the other things), you
  can [customize output names](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/wiki/Customize-output-file-names).

Unfortunately that's a uncaught `NullPointerException` and there isn't any details so it's hard to tell what is going wrong.